# How to find out if an element is in a fixed positioned container?

Tags: jquery, html, css-position

Say I have a nested `div` layout where **any** `div` **could have** a fixed position (CSS `position: fixed`):

```
<div class="MaybeIAmFixedToo">
    <div>
        <div class="MaybeIAmFixed">
            <div>
                <div id="IAmTheTarget">I am the target</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery reference of the innermost element: `$('#IAmTheTarget')`.

How can I (at best, without creating a performance nightmare :)) find out if my target is in a fixed positioned container? For example, `$('.MaybeIAmFixed')` could have a fixed position, but so could also any other parent of my target.

**Edit:**
I need to know this because when the element is fixed, I need to get its position with `$('#IAmTheTarget').position();` and if not, I need to get it with `$('#IAmTheTarget').offset();`

Comment: *"Don't do it, Anakin..."* But actually -- why would you want to do this? Worst-case scenario, you'd need to check every container up to the body for every element you're curious about.

Comment: I edited the question: If it's fixed I need to get the position differently for my library to work. Checking every container is indeed worst-case scenario, I was hoping there is a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't via any kind of simple selector. You *could* filter the element's parent list based on position, though:

```
var fixedp = $('#IAmTheTarget').parents().filter(
  function() {
    return $(this).css('position') == 'fixed';
  }
);

alert('fixed ancestors? ' + (fixedp.length ? "yes" : "no"));
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/axrFB

Comment: Will `.filter()` stop once it has found a fixed element or will it keep going through all the parents?

Comment: It will go through all of them. If you want to stop at the first match, you can loop over calls to `.parent()` until you find one that's fixed. Unless you're hundreds of levels deep, or running very frequently, I'd be surprised if there was much of a difference.

Comment: any non jquery version?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of the function Paul was mentioning, stopping at the first parent that is fixed :

```
function isElementFixed(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    while (!$el.is(document)) {
        if ($el.css("position") === "fixed") {
            return true;
        }
        $el = $el.parent();
    }
    return false;
}
```